# Pentaho Kettle connect to Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I'm trying to connect to Hadoop Cluster running on a Linux system using Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) which is running on Windows 10. While testing the connection I receive the following error: "**Hadoop File System Connection - Unable to connect to hostname xxx.xx.xx.xxx.**"

[image: ErrorImage]

Comment: Did you click "Learn more"? What's it say? What type of connection is it trying to make? You didn't give a port number

Answer (score -1):

have you solved this?
I copied four Hadoop conf files to `..\pentaho\pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342\data-integration\plugins\pentaho-big-data-plugin\hadoop-configurations\hdp26:`

- core-site.xml
- yarn-site.xml
- mapred-site.xml
- hdfs-site.xml

And check the `hostname/IPaddr` and port for the Hadoop cluster.